# restart execution of AsyncTask inside onCancelled

Tags: android

i am cancelling the currently running task inside from `doInBackground` by calling `cancel(false)` when some exception is being occured.

as i am calling cancel(false) it will let the currently running task finish and then `onCancelled` will be called.
now inside the `onCancelled` i want to re-execute the same task by calling `execute()` but i am getting following error at `execute()` function call

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute an AsyncTask more than once.

You should create a new instance of the task, like: `new MyAsyncTask().execute();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, man!  An AsyncTask has a lifecycle, represented in its internal state.  It can be executed only once.  Check the section on "Threading Rules" [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, "The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)"

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel the async task by caliing yourAsyncTask.cancel(true) and you can check before executing your async task if it is already running by getting its status